# BigQuery Query for GA Segment - Sequence

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a BigQuery SQL query which would tell me how many users have the following sequence (which is identical to GA segment)

[image]

I am not using legacy SQL.

I have tried using some mechanisms, yet to no avail.

Comment: Hi Andi and thank you for your question. Can you please add the latest SQL query you tried and explain what exactly is not working for you

Comment: Hi Tamir, I was trying to use those mechanisms with the help of pages: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45814378/page-sequence-paths-google-analytics-data-in-bigquery and this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860302/immediate-follow-page-path-in-bigquery . However, at one point I didn't get anywhere so I asked for help. Maybe a point in the direction I should take would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I see, Can you please add to your question the latest SQL you tried, You can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55610554/edit) to edit your question